# Codename One - BrowserComponent: make the web page always working in the background

Tags: codenameone

I have a BrowserComponent that loads a web page that does something by ajax every few seconds (suppose thirty seconds, I don't remember how many). These ajax requests get updates and keep the login.

My question is how to make the web page working when the app is in the background: sometimes the app works fine, other times it's killed by the o.s. when it's in the background (I suppose so because sometimes, when I reopen the app, it restarts).

There are apps that are never killed, such as media players, e-mail clients, etc.: how can I make my app always running in background? Of course I suppose that the CPU loading of my app is very low, but I didn't find any way to compare its cpu loading with other apps.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would find that hard to do with a web browser. Various OS's have different behaviors but even Android which used to be the least restrictive is moving towards a more restrictive background behavior to conserve battery life.

In the [misc section of the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html) we discuss the background modes e.g. background fetch etc.

You can do that from Codename One code which compiles to native but you can't leverage that from JavaScript as it doesn't give the OS enough control.

Comment: I tried to give a look at the page you linked, but there isn't anything about "Background Fetch" or "Background modes". However I've found these pages: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/background-fetch.html and https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/background/BackgroundFetch.html Where are the other background modes documented?

Comment: P.S.: Suppose that I have an app (with or without BrowserComponent) and that app implements (in Java) the performBackgroundFetch. Is it enough to keep the app working in background? For example, can I fetch "fake data" only with the purpose to prevent the o.s. from killing the app?

Comment: Probably not but who knows? That's a hack and even if it works for you neither Google nor Apple will guarantee that it will keep working. In fact both changed background behavior more than once.